# Htmlunit is not redirecting after click

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using `htmlunit` from `net.sourceforge.htmlunit` for simulating web browser. I try to log in in steam web app, but I encoutered problem. After setting credentials I wanted to use `click` method:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.setCookieManager(new CookieManager());

final HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(loginPageConfiguration.getLoginPageUrl());
final HtmlTextInput user = loginPage.getHtmlElementById(loginPageConfiguration.getLoginInputId());
user.setText(loginCredentials.getUsername());
final HtmlPasswordInput password = loginPage.getHtmlElementById(loginPageConfiguration.getPasswordInputId());
password.setText(loginCredentials.getPassword());
final HtmlPage afterLoginPage = loginPage.getHtmlElementById(loginPageConfiguration.getLoginButtonId()).click();
```

In normal browser after succesfull login it redirects to `http://store.steampowered.com/` but `afterLoginPage` is still in previous login page.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the page and having credentials to access i can only guess. Maybe the application is a single page application that replaces the visual content using ajax (maybe in combination with redirecting). Because ajax is async it might help to wait a bit after the click and before addressing the page.

It also might be a good starting point to understand what is going on by checking the http communication of the real browser (by using the developer tools or by using a web proxy like Charles). You can than compare this with the communication done by HtmlUnit (e.g. enable HttpClient wire log).

Another option might be a javascript error. Please check your log output.

Comment: `https://store.steampowered.com/login` after sucesfull login it should redirect to `http://store.steampowered.com/`

Comment: I tried to wait in loop, or add `waitForBackgroundJavaScript` but it was not working. Also `webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());`

Comment: @ByeBye: It's not unlikely that Steam has a security feature, which disables automation of their UI.

Comment: Will have a look if i can find some time. But the page looks like a real challenge....